# Partial match for number columns in a Spring Data JPA query

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I am working with a legacy system which requires doing a query for a partial match on a number field. So I want to do something like
`where ID like concat(:num, '%')` where num parameter is of the type `Long`. Is there a way to do that using Spring Data JPA derived queries. If the id was a string then I can simply do
`findByIdContaining(String id)`

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible with derived queries (those where the query is derived from the method name). But it's easy with an annotated `@Query` annotation.